# Two ROS computers - roswtf: WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition, roswtf, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unable to publish on /turtle1/cmd_vel with second controller computer, but it works fine on 1 computer. It works fine to send /clear service commands on 1 and 2 computer configurations.

Controller computer name computer2, node name is /rmdmia
Running Turtlesim on computer name computer1.

The following is output from roswtf:
WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:

- unknown (http://computer2:51117/)->/turtlesim (/turtle1/cmd_vel)

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /controlnode->/turtlesim (/turtle1/cmd_vel)

It appears to be a DNS issue, but I've set up the hosts file in both systems with each computer's ethernet ip address, set the ros_ip, and ros_hostname on computer1, and set the ros_master_uri on both systems to the hostname, instead of localhost. Any idea where the configuration is wrong?

Thanks,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215493/two-ros-computers---roswtf:-warning-the-following-nodes-are-unexpectedly-connected:/) by [unknown_entity2](https://answers.ros.org/users/23243/unknown_entity2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out to be an XMLRPC problem. The requestTopic method had a variable that always made the address localhost, and therefore the publisher worked on localhost, and subscribers, and services always seemed to work.

Thanks,

Aaron

---

Originally posted by [unknown_entity2](https://answers.ros.org/users/23243/unknown_entity2/) with karma: 16 on 2015-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-05**:
I'm a bit confused: normal ROS setups never have to change anything in XMLRPC libraries. All configuration is done using `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` (as suggested by @TomSon). For two PCs and no working DNS, set `ROS_IP`on both and `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the IP of `roscore` machine.

**Comment by [unknown_entity2](https://answers.ros.org/users/23243/unknown_entity2/) on 2015-09-08**:
You are correct that it is not a normal ROS setup. I am a developer, and it was a client I've been developing.